# Как вставить эмодзи в Юникоде в мета-теги сайта на Битрикс?

Tags: битрикс, seo, unicode

Через умный фильтр добавил эмодзи (`&#128293;`) в мета-тег description, но вместо картинки выводится вот такая штука `&amp;#128293`;. Насколько я понимаю это особенность Битрикс и других CMS. Причем после того как я их добавил все работало нормально, но потом слетело. Как это исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Добавь без экранирования. Просто  вместо `&#128293;`

Comment: так тоже пробовал. иногда он выводит картинки, оно если их несколько то может выводить только некоторые из них. а бывает что ничего не выводит, а только добавляет пробелы в те места где должны быть эмодзи

Answer (score 0):

Нужно использовать функцию html_entity_decode:

```
echo html_entity_decode('&#128293;')
```

Но, конечно, если в используемом на странице шрифте такого символа нет, то будет выдан символ по умолчанию.

Тестовый пример:

```
<?
require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/bitrix/header.php");
?>
<?
$APPLICATION->SetPageProperty('description','огонь&#128293;');
?>
<?
$APPLICATION->SetPageProperty('description', html_entity_decode($APPLICATION->GetPageProperty('description')));
?>
<?
require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/bitrix/footer.php");
?>
```

Результат: http://joxi.ru/Dr8LwVpCDL36pr

Comment: А как это вывести через умный фильтр?

Comment: Наверное, как любую другую строку. Указанная функция просто делает в строке замену кодов символов на сами символы.

Comment: что значит как любую другую строку? ее прямо сюда писать что ли? http://linkme.ufanet.ru/images/f1d18ff085c486f8e6ecfb4d7a49f625.png

Comment: После компонента на странице вставьте ```<?$APPLICATION->SetPageProperty('description', html_entity_decode($APPLICATION->GetPageProperty('description')));?>```.

Comment: Так? если да, то ничего не изменилось `<?$APPLICATION->ShowMeta("description");?>
 <?$APPLICATION->SetPageProperty('description', html_entity_decode($APPLICATION->GetPageProperty('description')));?>`

Comment: Не в шапке, а после компонента. После $APPLICATION->IncludeComponent. Вставленный компонент выставляет свойство страницы description, а мы это свойство тут же правим.

Comment: Чет я не врубаюсь о каком компоненте идет речь. разве description не этим вызывается? `<?$APPLICATION->ShowMeta("description");?>`

Comment: Нет, здесь description всего лишь рисуется на странице. А определяется он в компоненте bitrix:news или bitrix:catalog или какой там ещё на твоей странице расположен. Определяется по настройкам SEO соответствующего инфоблока. Вот после того места, где на странице вставлен компонент, вставь указанный код, который подправит description.

Comment: description выводится через seo умного фильтра (аспро)

Comment: Ну, можно тогда править description в конце страницы, когда он уже определён.

Comment: то есть почти то что я сделал выше, только в конце страницы. но результат тот же

Comment: В ответе написал тестовый пример и результат. Странно, что у тебя не получается. Возможно, не на той странице правишь.

Comment: Вы это руками прописали ? Так у меня тоже нормально все отображается и без дополнительных усилий. Но мне нужно выводить через Умный фильтр (аспро)

Comment: Ну так вставьте исправление desсription после компонента Умный фильтр. Либо в шаблоне Умного фильтра.

Comment: поправочка: description выводится через seo умного фильтра. это не компонент. а еще я пробовал вставить исправление в футере. это не сработало

Comment: Возможно, умный фильтр экранирует html символы, тогда их нужно будет предварительно разэкранировать.

Comment: я пробовал и так &#128293; и так  вставлять. результат тот же

Comment: Я смотрю, у тебя в <head> стоит не ```&#128293;```, а ```&amp;#128293;```. То есть символ  заэкранирован дважды. Значит, нужно применить функцию html_entity_decode дважды. В первый раз она исправит &amp; на &, а во второй - &#128293; на 

Comment: я так и пишу в УФ http://linkme.ufanet.ru/images/249f1d7058399756492c4d7f58b7f9b5.png, но на выходе получается то что получается.

Comment: Ты пишешь ```&#128293;```. Фильтр экранирует амперсанд и выдаёт в description ```&amp;#128293;```. Если применить к description функцию html_entity_decode один раз, получится ```&#128293;```. А если применить к результату функцию html_entity_decode ещё раз, получится . То есть в конце страницы нужно добавить двойной вызов: ```<?$APPLICATION->SetPageProperty('description', html_entity_decode(html_entity_decode($APPLICATION->GetPageProperty('description'))));?>```

Comment: звучит логично, но не работает. на выходе все равно получается &amp;#128293;. похоже что функция вообще не работает. можно как то проверить ?

Comment: Проверить футер. Может, там description задаётся. И править его там. Можно под админским аккаунтом вставить вывод ``` if($USER->IsAdmin()) echo ($APPLICATION->GetPageProperty('description');``` в разных местах, чтобы увидеть, где задаётся description.